# Swift CVCalendar not updating monthLabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, cvcalendar

I recently started using CVCalendar to create a CalendarView with a Week presentation.

I created a `UILabel` called `monthLabel` which has an outlet to the view's controller

[image]

The ViewController for this particular view is this one:

```
import UIKit
import CVCalendar

class EventsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var headerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuView: CVCalendarMenuView!
    @IBOutlet weak var calendarView: CVCalendarView!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventsTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var monthLabel: UILabel!
    
    private var currentCalendar: Calendar?
    private var animationFinished: Bool = true
    
    let mainAppViewHeader: MainAppViewHeader = UIView.fromNib()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        loadViewHeader()
        setupTable()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        setupDatePicker()
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let timeZoneBias = 480 // (UTC+08:00)
        currentCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        currentCalendar?.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
        if let timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -timeZoneBias * 60) {
            currentCalendar?.timeZone = timeZone
        }
    }
    
    func setupDatePicker() {
        menuView.delegate = self
        calendarView.delegate = self
        
        menuView.backgroundColor = ColorManager.Gray5
        calendarView.backgroundColor = ColorManager.Gray5
        
        calendarView.appearance.dayLabelPresentWeekdaySelectedBackgroundColor = ColorManager.PrimaryColor
        calendarView.appearance.dayLabelWeekdaySelectedBackgroundColor = ColorManager.PrimaryColor
        
        if let currentCalendar = currentCalendar {
            monthLabel.text = CVDate(date: Date(), calendar: currentCalendar).globalDescription
        }
        
        menuView.commitMenuViewUpdate()
        calendarView.commitCalendarViewUpdate()
    }
    
    func loadViewHeader() {
        mainAppViewHeader.setupHeader()
        headerView.addSubview(mainAppViewHeader)
    }
    
    func setupTable() {
        let rowNib = UINib(nibName: "EventTableCell", bundle: nil)
        
        eventsTable.dataSource = self
        eventsTable.delegate = self
        
        eventsTable.register(rowNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "eventCell")
        eventsTable.separatorStyle = .none
    }
}

extension EventsViewController: CVCalendarViewDelegate, CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate {
    func presentationMode() -> CalendarMode {
        return .weekView
    }
    
    func firstWeekday() -> Weekday {
        return .sunday
    }
    
    func shouldAutoSelectDayOnWeekChange() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func disableScrollingBeforeDate() -> Date {
        let currentDate = Date()
        return currentDate.addingTimeInterval(-8 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    }
    
    func disableScrollingBeyondDate() -> Date {
        let currentDate = Date()
        return currentDate.addingTimeInterval(180 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    }
    
    func maxSelectableRange() -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func shouldSelectRange() -> Bool {
        false
    }
    
    func earliestSelectableDate() -> Date {
        let currentDate = Date()
        return currentDate.addingTimeInterval(-8 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    }
    
    func latestSelectableDate() -> Date {
        let currentDate = Date()
        return currentDate.addingTimeInterval(180 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    }
    
    func shouldShowWeekdaysOut() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func didShowPreviousWeekView(from startDayView: DayView, to endDayView: DayView) {
        print(startDayView, endDayView)
    }
    
    func presentedDateUpdated(_ date: CVDate) {
        monthLabel.text = "asdf" //calendarView.presentedDate.globalDescription
        print(date.globalDescription)
    }
}

extension EventsViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let eventCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell") as? EventTableCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        
        eventCell.setupCell()
        eventCell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        
        return eventCell
    }
}

extension EventsViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
}
```

And the outlet reference:

[image]

The issue here is that even tho I'm telling the UILabel to change its text whenever the presented date is updated:

```
func presentedDateUpdated(_ date: CVDate) {
    monthLabel.text = "asdf" //calendarView.presentedDate.globalDescription
    print(date.globalDescription)
}
```

It's not updating its value, yet I get the `date.globalDescription` value printed in the console.

Is there something I'm missing when trying to update the label?

I tried using the code in the [official example](https://github.com/CVCalendar/CVCalendar/blob/master/CVCalendar%20Demo/CVCalendar%20Demo/ViewController.swift#L118):

```
func presentedDateUpdated(_ date: CVDate) {
    if monthLabel.text != date.globalDescription && self.animationFinished {
        let updatedMonthLabel = UILabel()
        updatedMonthLabel.textColor = monthLabel.textColor
        updatedMonthLabel.font = monthLabel.font
        updatedMonthLabel.textAlignment = .center
        updatedMonthLabel.text = date.globalDescription
        updatedMonthLabel.sizeToFit()
        updatedMonthLabel.alpha = 0
        updatedMonthLabel.center = self.monthLabel.center
        
        let offset = CGFloat(48)
        updatedMonthLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: offset)
        updatedMonthLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 0.1)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, delay: 0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.animationFinished = false
            self.monthLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -offset)
            self.monthLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 0.1)
            self.monthLabel.alpha = 0
            
            updatedMonthLabel.alpha = 1
            updatedMonthLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            
        }) { _ in
            
            self.animationFinished = true
            self.monthLabel.frame = updatedMonthLabel.frame
            self.monthLabel.text = updatedMonthLabel.text
            self.monthLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            self.monthLabel.alpha = 1
            updatedMonthLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        
        self.view.insertSubview(updatedMonthLabel, aboveSubview: self.monthLabel)
    }
}
```

But this approach is only pushing a new view with the updated month and then dismissing the view, and while it contains basically the same code that I was using:

```
self.monthLabel.text = updatedMonthLabel.text
```

The `monthLabel` is not being updated, this is what happens when using the above code, it reverts back to original text.

[image]

If I remove this line:

```
updatedMonthLabel.removeFromSuperview()
```

Both texts get overlapped, so it's ignoring this line:

```
self.monthLabel.text = updatedMonthLabel.text
```

[image]

---

I've done some extra testing, and checked that the label is correctly linked with an outlet to my view, I changed the text color:

```
func presentedDateUpdated(_ date: CVDate) {
        print(Thread.current)
        print("Wololo")
        monthLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
        monthLabel.text = "asdf"
//        calendarView.contentController.refreshPresentedMonth()
//        monthLabel.text = "asdf" //calendarView.presentedDate.globalDescription
//        print(date.globalDescription)
    }
```

It prints:

```
<NSThread: 0x600002b6c100>{number = 1, name = main}
Wololo
```

N number of times I change the day by clicking on the calendar, however the text remains unchanged:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the code inside:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    let timeZoneBias = 480 // (UTC+08:00)
    currentCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    currentCalendar?.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
    if let timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -timeZoneBias * 60) {
        currentCalendar?.timeZone = timeZone
    }
}
```

was in conflict with not updating the label, if we remove the above code and instead do this:

```
func setupDatePicker() {
    menuView.delegate = self
    calendarView.delegate = self
    
    menuView.commitMenuViewUpdate()
    calendarView.commitCalendarViewUpdate()
    
    monthLabel.text = calendarView.presentedDate.globalDescription //This line at the bottom of this method
}
```

Everything works once again.

If someone knows the reason behind it, feel free to make a comment and I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`presentedDateUpdated` is likely being called on a background thread making it so your UI changes aren't being displayed. you can confirm this by printing `Thread.current` inside `presentedDateUpdated`.

a simple solution would be this:

```swift
func presentedDateUpdated(_ date: CVDate) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.monthLabel.text = "asdf" //calendarView.presentedDate.globalDescription
        print(date.globalDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Same behavior, text on the `UILabel` still not being updated

Comment: When printing `Thread.current` inside the method, I get: `<NSThread: 0x600001608dc0>{number = 1, name = main}`